# list of checkboxes ng-click returning always the first element when any other is clicked, ng-disabled not working

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-ng-disabled

I gave a grid of checkboxes, whenever I try to click any it passes always the same one in the `ng-click`

**HTML**

```
<tr ng-repeat="partecipant in current_event.partecipants">
                        <td class="user_cell"><font class="user_name">{{(partecipant}}</font><span class="arrow"></td>
                        <td class="checkbox_cell" ng-repeat="proposed_time in current_event.proposed">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="toggle" ng-checked="isChecked(partecipant, proposed_time)" ng-true-value="true"  ng-false-value="false" ng-click="addResponse(partecipant, proposed_time)" ng-disabled="userProfile.webid != partecipant" name="thing" id="thing"><label for="thing">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

`ng-checked`: works fine, the checkboxes are checked accordingly

`ng-click`: not working, it passes always the first value of `proposed_time`

`ng-disabled`: not working, the are all enabled, when they should be enabled  only for one row when `userProfile.webid == partecipant`

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Solved!

The error was in `name="thing" id="thing"` that makes the checkboxes have the same name and id, therefor I named them dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code.

```
{{(partecipant}}
```

Here you have not closed brace '('

Other than that everything works, ng-click and ng-disabled are ok.
Check [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/jod2u6t938nrWn1g75qE?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you for the plunker, I will check it out. That has nothing to do with the error, it was for demonstration purposes and I edited it in the post :)